# Using Python's max to return two equally large values

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I'm using Python's [max](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) function to find the largest integer in a dictionary called `count`, and the corresponding key (not quite sure if I'm saying it properly; my code probably explains itself better than I'm explaining it). The dictionary `count` is along the lines of `{'a': 100, 'b': 210}`, and so on.

```
number = count[max(count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]]
highest = max(count, key=count.get)
```

What would I do if there were two equal largest values in there? If I had `{'a': 120, 'b': 120, 'c': 100}`, this would only find the first of `a` and `b`, not both.

Comment: What you do seems overly complex. Fox example: `number = max(count.values())`.

Comment: I can't resist one-liners for these kinds of questions `highest, number = reduce(lambda a, b:a[0].append(b[0]) or (a[0], b[1]) if b[1] == a[1] else (([b[0]], b[1]) if b[1] > a[1] else a), count.iteritems(), ([], -1))`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Idea is to find max value and get all keys corresponding to that value:

```
count = {'a': 120, 'b': 120, 'c': 100}

highest = max(count.values())

print([k for k, v in count.items() if v == highest])
```

Comment: Could you explain a little regarding what Python's doing here? I'm quite new to it.

Comment: 1. count.values() returns list of values, e.g. [120, 120, 100]. 2. max(count.values()) returns a max value from list, e.g. 120. 3. count.items() returns a list of (key, value) tuples, e.g. [('a', 120), ('b', 120), ('c', 100)]. The last line is called list comprehension. You can rewrite the same code as follows. Iterate through (key, value) pairs in the dictionary, and if value is the same as highest, then add key to a list.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way not to print the brackets?

Comment: Could this same code be applied if instead 'a','b' and 'c' were columns of a data frame?

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as Asterisk, but without iterating over the list twice. Bit more verbose.

```
count = { 'a': 120, 'b': 120, 'c': 100 }
answers = []
highest = -1

def f(x):
    global highest, answers
    if count[x] > highest:
        highest = count[x]
        answers = [x]
    elif count[x] == highest:
        answers.append(x)

map(f, count.keys())
print answers
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast single pass:

```
a = { 'a': 120, 'b': 120, 'c': 100 }
z = [0]
while a:
    key, value = a.popitem()
    if value > z[0]:
        z = [value,[key]]
    elif value == z[0]:
        z[1].append(key)

print z
#output:
[120, ['a', 'b']]
```

And an amusing way with [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
b = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in a.iteritems():
    b[value].append(key)
print max(b.items())
#output:
(120, ['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: As an intermediate result you have a map of (value -> [keys]) for all values. This fact (additional data structures) makes it quite slow (but quite elegant).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way (probably not the most efficient).

```
value = max(count.values())
filter(lambda key: count[key]==value,count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simplest solution may be the best:

```
max_value = 0
max_keys = []

for k, v in count.items():
    if v >= max_value:
        if v > max_value:
            max_value = v
            max_keys = [k]
        else:
            max_keys.append(k)

print max_keys
```

The code above is slightly faster than two pass solution like:

```
highest = max(count.values())
print [k for k,v in count.items() if v == highest]
```

Of course it's longer, but on the other hand it's very clear and easy to read.

Comment: I forgot to mention - this is a Python 3.x solution, it you are using Python 2.x, you should replace count.items() by count.iteritems().

Comment: Worth nothing that `count.items()` will work in Python 2.x as well (albeit not as efficiently).

Answer (score -1):

To print a list without bucket. use :

```
' '.join(map(str, mylist))
```

or, more verbosely:

```
' '.join(str(x) for x in mylist)
```