# List of the most recently updated files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So using the following piece of code I can easily find the most recently updated file in a folder:

```
files = os.listdir(UPLOAD_DIR+"/"+configData[obj]["client_name"])
paths = [os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIR+"/"+configData[obj]["client_name"], basename) for basename in files]
file = max(paths, key=os.path.getctime)
```

But what if there are two or more files that have the exact same updated time? How do I get a list of such files?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but hardcoding path seprators (`UPLOAD_DIR+"/"+configData[obj]["client_name"]) kind of defeats the whole point of `os.path.join()`. This should be `os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIR, configData[obj]["client_name"], basename)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the maximums max function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823227/how-to-get-all-the-maximums-max-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest code: find the latest ctime, then get all files having this latest ctime:

```
def most_recent(paths):
    if not paths:
        return []
    latest_ctime = max(os.path.getctime(p) for p in paths)
    most_recent_files = [p for p in paths if os.path.getctime(p)==latest_ctime]
    return most_recent_files
```

We loop twice over the list of paths, though, and there is a risk of race condition if the ctime of the most recent file changes between the two loops: in this case, it wouldn't be found again in the second loop.

We can do it in one loop, with a little bit more code, eliminating the race condition:

```
def most_recent_one_loop(paths):
    out = []
    latest_ctime = 0
    for p in paths:
        ct = os.path.getctime(p)
        if ct > latest_ctime:
            latest_ctime = ct
            out = [p]
        elif ct == latest_ctime:
            out.append(p)
    return out
```

As we can expect, this is about twice as fast (about 100 paths in the folder for the test):

```
%timeit most_recent(paths)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 477 µs per loop

%timeit most_recent_one_loop(paths)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 239 µs per loop
```

Comment: race condition ahead

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Yes, I added a way to do it in one loop to avoid that.

Comment: it will be great to add that race conditions are unavoidable here without some sort of mechanism for "blocking" files, but this is a different and IMO harder question

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the tidiest way of doing it but:

```
maxval = os.path.getctime(max(paths, key=os.path.getctime))

indices = [index for index, val in enumerate(paths) if os.path.getctime(val) == maxval]
for index in indices:
    print(paths[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3, look like the max method can't fix your issue , as the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) explicitly state:

> If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered. This is consistent with other sort-stability preserving tools such as sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc, reverse=True)[0] and heapq.nlargest(1, iterable, key=keyfunc).

You may need to use sorted command to find the multi max value

```
list = sorted(paths, key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
files=[]
for i in list:
  if os.path.getctime(list[0]) == os.path.getctime(i):
    files.append(i)
  else:
    break
```