# One line for and if python

Tags: python

I try to understand the working of the python one-line method... So I decided to code this :

```
pizza_result=[[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 0]]
b=0
pizza_result=[i for i in  pizza_result if i[1]>=b]
```

But Now I would like change the value of b...

As:

```
izza_result=[i for i in  pizza_result if i[1]>=b: b=i[1] ]
```

But this doesn't work...

Where I have to but the `=i[1]`?

In a nutshell :

**What I expect**

I would like the element(s) who have the biggest i[1]

**In This code what's aim the output ?**

Here, I just want [[2,3]] because i[1] (3) > the other

**BUT**

But if I had : [[1,1],[2,1],[3,0]] I expect have : [[1,1],[2,1]]. Because the second number is >

Comment: What do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: I would like the element(s) who have the biggest i[1]

Comment: Here, I just want [[2,3]] because i[1] (3) > the other

Comment: But if I had : [[1,1],[2,1],[3,0]] I expect have : [[1,1],[2,1]]

Comment: Then use a `max`. An XY problem here.

Comment: Please include this information in your question.

Comment: You need to execute the third line again after changing `b`. The last line (the one that doesn't work) is useless. You don't have to write `=i[1]` anywhere.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

Comment: Fundamentally this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823227/how-to-get-all-the-maximums-max-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` to first get max value, and then use list comprehension to filter:

```py
pizza_result=[[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 0], [4, 3]]

max_val = max(p[1] for p in pizza_result)
output = [x for x in pizza_result if x[1] == max_val]
print(output) # [[2, 3], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 I agree! Also that makes even more sense if the list is long.

Answer (score 0):

"*I would like the element(s) who have the biggest i[1]*"

Use:

```
m = max(pizza_result, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
[l for l in pizza_result if l[1] == m]
```

Output: `[[2, 3], [4, 3]]`

Comment: Ok, now it works, though I think it's pretty much the same as the other answer, just not as good. NB. I don't see the point of explaining a downvote when you can easily explain it yourself by testing.

Comment: Add I said, this was a typo during copying the answer ;)