# Python: Counting maximum occurences of an item in a list with ties allowed

Tags: python, list, max

Right now I am using the classic counting of occurences in a list
`max(lst,key=lst.count)` but if there is a tie in the maximum occurences of two different elements e.g `lst = [1,1,2,2]`, `max` returns only one element. In our example it will return `1` or `2` . But I need a function which will return both `1` and `2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Python's max to return two equally large values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853302/using-pythons-max-to-return-two-equally-large-values)

Comment: check this out : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987285/find-the-item-with-maximum-occurrences-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a `Counter` from the list and take the items that match the highest count using a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [1,1,2,2]

c = Counter(lst)
maximums = [x for x in c if c[x] == c.most_common(1)[0][1]]
print(maximums)
# [1, 2]
```

The `Counter` approach take counts in one pass (O(n)) whereas the `list.count` approach has O(n^2) time complexity as it passes through the list with each call.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution but it definitely works. First you find the number of the maximum occurrence, then find the elements with that count.

```
lst = [1,1,2,2,3,4]
max_count = max([lst.count(i) for i in set(lst)])
max_count_values = [i for i in set(lst) if lst.count(i)==max_count]
```

Comment: This has O(n^2) time complexity as it uses `list.count` repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: By not being the most elegant solution as stated, it's not a surprise that my solution wasn't optimal either. But I think I make up for it as easiest to understand for a beginning programmer while also not needing to install/use any modules.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, as finding the single most common number in a list is trivial with [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html), but there is nothing quite so simple if you want to find all of the different modes.

Calling `list.count` for each value is needlessly expensive, as this uses `O(n^2)` time, but computing the counts of each element only requires `O(n)` time.

Here is a solution using NumPy:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst = [1,1,2,2,3]
>>> values, counts = np.unique(lst, return_counts=True)
>>> values[np.argwhere(counts == counts.max())].flatten()
array([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner, but perhaps not the clearest.

```
set(x for x in lst if lst.count(x)==max(lst.count(x) for x in lst))
```

Comment: This has at least quadratic time complexity, maybe even cubic.